# Using an Arduino Uno to program AT32UC3B

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmel, programmer

Is it possible to use the Arduino as a programmer for an Atmel 32 bit microprocessor? I have tried searching for something and was not able to find anything. If anyone could give any insight that would be much appreciated. 
On a side note, I am looking to get this microprocessor (http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/AT32UC3B0128-A2UT/AT32UC3B0128-A2UT-ND/1769692)

Comment: You would have to turn the Arduino into a JTAG programmer. I see no reason why this should not work in principle, but in practice, I’m not sure anybody has implemented this yet. See https://github.com/balau/JTAGduino for one effort.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you.
I am looking for a low power, but powerful microcontroller that can be programmed easily. Do you have any suggestions? I have only ever used the ATMega328p, but I am looking for something with a bit more power.

Comment: Let's say I were to get a JTAGICE3, what wire/connection would be necessary?

Answer (score 5):

The AT32UCxxx series microcontrollers do not have simple SPI In-System Programming like the smaller 8bit Atmel microcontrollers do. They require ICE-JTAG to be programmed. [You can make a AVR Jtag Ice clone.](http://www.scienceprog.com/build-your-own-avr-jtagice-clone/) Not sure how compatible that would be with any given Arduino or the Arduino Bootloader though.

But the other way of programming the AT32UCxxx series is... [The built in USB bootloader it ships with.](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc7745.pdf). No specialized hardware programmer needed. All you need is a usb cable (or cable + jack) and two series resistors, on top of the all ready required power supply and passives.

[This site](http://www.core.st/projects/AVR32_Starter_Kit/AVR32_Board.html) has the instructions to build a working bare-bones AT32UC3B board from scratch.